# C# how to conver a string "-" into a double

Tags: c#

Hello I was wondering how to return a string value = "-" inside a double method,
what I have so far is:

```
public double Percent
        {
            get
            {
                if (TotalTime != 0)
                {
                    double percentage = (double)Completion / (double)TotalTime;
                    if (percentage == Double.NaN)
                        return 0;
                    else
                        return percentage;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Convert.ToDouble("-");
                }
            }
        }
```

But I do not know how I can return "-", this part of the code breaks return Convert.ToDouble("-");

I tried return Convert.ToDouble("-"); and I expect to return "-"

Comment: `-` is not a number so you can not convert it to double.

Comment: do you mean to return a "negative" like -1, -10 value? If it's not then possibly you are trying to return a string "-"

Comment: Why would you expect a method that converts a value to a `double` to return a `string`? That makes no sense. If you want to be able to represent no value for a numeric type like `double` then you should be using a nullable, i.e. `double?`, which is shorthand for `Nullable<double>`. It would then be up to your presentation logic to display a dash in the UI where no value was present.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. As Christian has mentioned in his answer (which hopefully you have read by now), you are mixing business logic with presentation. Your code should be geared to produce logical results (in this case, the percentage of completion) which is a numeric value of type double. Your presentation layer should figure out how to display that value (in this case, show a minus sign when no time has been spent).

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing here, so this might be totally off.

It looks like you either want to return your `TotalTime` percentage as a double. Or, if that is not possible (due to TotalTime being 0), return a string indicating that, for which you choose simply a dash.

In the output of an application that would then look something like this:

| % Total Time |
| --- |
| 74.38% |
| - |
| 20.00% |

Now, if that is not what you are looking for, then please indicate so in a comment, and I can remove this answer.

You simply cannot express both with a double - at least not directly as you have found out. `-` is not a valid representation of a double, and thus you cannot return it as such.

You have to differentiate between what you show/display and what you internally use.

Internally, you can represent the "no TotalTime available" situation with a special "double value", and only when displaying the results, convert that to a string (e.g. "-").

You could do the following:

###### Using `Double.NaN` (look up [what it means](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.nan?view=net-6.0)) to represent no value available:

```
    public double Percent
    {
        get
        {
            if (TotalTime != 0)
            {
                // Snip
            }
            else
            {
                return Double.NaN;
            }
        }
    }
```

When displaying your Percent values, check for `Double.IsNaN(Precent)` and if true display a `"-"` instead of the actual `Percent.ToString()`.

###### Return a nullable double

```
    public double? Percent
    {
        get
        {
            if (TotalTime != 0)
            {
                // Snip
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

When displaying your Percent values, check for `Percent.HasValue` and if false display a `"-"` instead of the actual `Percent.Value.ToString()`.

###### Return value and validity information at once

```
    public (double Value, bool IsValid) Percent
    {
        get
        {
            if (TotalTime != 0)
            {
                double percentage = (double)Completion / (double)TotalTime;
                // Unrelated, but this check is wrong!
                //    if (percentage == Double.NaN)
                // Needs to be like this:
                if (Double.IsNaN(percentage))
                    return (0, true);
                else
                    return (percentage, true);
            }
            else
            {
                return (0, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

When displaying your Percent values, check for `Percent.IsValid` and if true display a `Percent.Value.ToString()`, if it is false, display a `"-"`.

There are more options to achieve this. But it boils down to, as said, separating the actual data from its representation.

Comment: Nice answer, Christian. I would personally prefer to return zero (`0`) on situations where TotalTime is zero (`0`) as no time spent should be a valid state with a valid percentage (0%). How the GUI displays that is a different story. Also, it should be noted the OP's post has a temporal dependency that can result in a runtime error so adding a try/catch error handler or code to check for division by zero would not be a bad idea either... :-)

Comment: @juanr Yes, the whole idea behind it could be improved. I was not trying to go into that (except for the `Double.IsNan()`-thing) as that might be different question, with a different answer (and makeing this one even longer ;-)). I don't understand this `has a temporal dependency that can result in a runtime error` though.

Comment: @JuanR Oh, I get it. You mean that `TotalTime` might change (to 0) after it has been check for not being so, but before the division using it is made. In other words a (data) race condition. Well, assuming that this code is running in MT scenarios is of course not wrong, but neither is it a given. Because the OP seems to be rather new to the subject matter, I would assume it is not. Additionally, adding this concern to the answer would totally overload it. Moreso, the correct fix would then, IMO, not be adding try/catch but prevening the data race using proper synchronization (lock, etc.).

Comment: Agreed. These are just additional points for other people who may read this. I agree that it would further confuse the OP.
Because the code is dependent on an external field (`TotalTime`), it will blow if the property is not set to something other than zero. This of course could be enforced (e.g. via a constructor value initializer and a read-only property or something of the sort), but it's a pattern I particularly dislike and one I come across way too often.
Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I was searching for, sorry if I wasn't clear enough (english is my second language)

Comment: If it did help you, it would be nice (and beneficial to the Q&A system), to mark this answer as accepted.